# firebase phoneNumber not saving as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a small react app that I am building with firebase auth.
When I try to update a user profile as follows:

```
        auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
            displayName: firstnameRef.current.value+" "+surnameRef.current.value, 
            phoneNumber: "+11234567890",
            photoURL: "www.photo.com"
        })
```

The display name and photoURL save, however the phoneNumber does not.
Is there any reason for this. I am not getting any errors when attempting to save.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `updatePhoneNumber()` function to update user's phone number.

```
auth.currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(phoneCredential)
```

`phoneCredential` is an `AuthCredential` object as mentioned in the [docoumentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#get-the-intermediate-authcredential-object).